# Подключение к woocommerce из UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, wordpress, uwp, woocommerce

Добрый день.

Пишу приложение для UWP (C#)

Стоит задача подключиться к Woocommerce

Нашел интересный плагин для UWP

[Плагин](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET)

Мой код для подключения

```
 // RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://www.simplegames.com.ua/wc-api/v3/", "ck_f03bbd67e26a96604ddb188dbd63be3d252891ab", "cs_f8583f42dd1d75da832574b7ad6e649a0687f88f");
            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://www.simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v2/" ,"ck_f03bbd67e26a96604ddb188dbd63be3d252891ab", "cs_f8583f42dd1d75da832574b7ad6e649a0687f88f");

            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            //Get all products
            var products = await wc.GetOrders();


            Debug.WriteLine(products);
```

Но при запуске дает такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто сталкивался с этим?

помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 1):

Написано же, что авторизация не пройдена (401 ошибка это Unauthorized). Здесь смотрели http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication ?

Comment: Правда?

я знаю авторизация не про1дена

да, смотрел, Consumer Secret и Comsumer key есть сгенерированный как видите из кода